# How to force WebKit (in QtWebView) to use actual windows for HTML elements?

Tags: webkit, qtwebkit, browser-plugin

There is windowful video playing plugin (with gstreamer inside). I want things to be placed atop of it.

Can WebKit be forced to use real windows for non-embeds? Can in control their z-order?

Currently even if I intersect two windowful embeds they get *random* z-order disregarding my "z-index" CSS property.